# Conditional rolling sum across columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, lapply, rowsum

I have a data frame of values across successive years (columns) for unique individuals (rows). A dummy data example is provided here:

```
dt = structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), `2015` = c(0, 
0.8219178, 0, 0.1369863, 0, 1.369863, 0.2739726, 0.8219178, 5, 
0), `2016` = c(0, 1.369863, 0, 0.2739726, 0, 0.2739726, 0, 3.2876712, 
0, 0), `2017` = c(0.6849315, 0, 0, 0.6849315, 0, 0.5479452, 0, 
0, 0, 0), `2018` = c(1.0958904, 0.5479452, 1.9178082, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 3), `2019` = c(0, 0, 0, 1.0958904, 0, 0.9589041, 0.5479452, 
0, 0, 0), `2020` = c(0.4383562, 0, 0, 0, 0.2739726, 0.6849315, 
0, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

I want to create a dataset where the maximum value for each individual that should appear for each year is 1. In cases where it exceeds this value, I want to carry the excess value over 1 into the next year (column) and sum it to that year's value for each individual and so on.

The expected result is:

```
dt_expected = structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), `2015` = c(0, 
0.8219178, 0, 0.1369863, 0, 1, 0.2739726, 0.8219178, 1, 0), `2016` = c(0, 
1, 0, 0.2739726, 0, 0.6438356, 0, 1, 1, 0), `2017` = c(0.6849315, 
0.369863, 0, 0.6849315, 0, 0.5479452, 0, 1, 1, 0), `2018` = c(1, 
0.5479452, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), `2019` = c(0.0958904, 0, 
0.9178082, 1, 0, 0.9589041, 0.5479452, 0.2876712, 1, 1), `2020` = c(0.4383562, 
0, 0, 0.0958904, 0.2739726, 0.6849315, 0, 0, 0, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I am at a total loss of where to start with this problem, so any assistance achieving this using `data.table` would be greatly appreciated. My only thought is to use `lapply` with an `ifelse` function for the conditional component. Then should I be using `rowSums` or `Reduce` to achieve my outcome of shifting excess values across columns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A translation of Martin Morgan's answer to [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
for (i in 2:(ncol(dt) - 1)) {
  x = dt[[i]]
  set(dt, j = i, value = pmin(x, 1))
  set(dt, j = i + 1, value = dt[[i + 1L]] + pmax(x - 1, 0))
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Not particularly pretty or efficient, but as a starting point I used `pmin()` and `pmax()` to update each year (and the subsequent year), iteratively. The current year is the minimum of the current year and 1 (`pmin(x, 1)`); the subsequent year is the current subsequent year plus the excess of the previous year (`pmax(x - 1, 0)`)

```
update <- function(df) {
    result = df
    for (idx in 2:(ncol(df) - 1)) {
        x = result[[ idx ]]
        result[[ idx ]] = pmin(x, 1)
        result[[ idx + 1 ]] = result[[ idx + 1 ]] + pmax(x - 1, 0)
    }
    result
}
```

We have

```
> all.equal(update(dt), dt_expected)
[1] TRUE
```

I don't know how to translate this into efficient data.table syntax, but the function 'works' as is on a data.table, `update(as.data.table(dt))`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there is a more efficient way with built in functions, but I simply wrote a recursive function that implements your described algorithm for the rows and then apply it over every row.

```r
f <- function(l, rest = 0, out = list()) {
  if (length(l) == 0) return(unlist(out))
  if (l[[1]] + rest <= 1) {
    f(l[-1], rest = 0, out = append(out, list(l[[1]] + rest)))
  } else (
    f(l[-1], rest = l[[1]] + rest - 1, out = append(out, list(1)))
  )
}

dt[-1] <- apply(dt[-1], 1, f, simplify = F) |> 
  do.call(what = rbind)

dt
#> # A tibble: 10 × 7
#>       ID `2015` `2016` `2017` `2018` `2019` `2020`
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1     1  0      0      0.685  1     0.0959 0.438 
#>  2     2  0.822  1      0.370  0.548 0      0     
#>  3     3  0      0      0      1     0.918  0     
#>  4     4  0.137  0.274  0.685  0     1      0.0959
#>  5     5  0      0      0      0     0      0.274 
#>  6     6  1      0.644  0.548  0     0.959  0.685 
#>  7     7  0.274  0      0      0     0.548  0     
#>  8     8  0.822  1      1      1     0.288  0     
#>  9     9  1      1      1      1     1      0     
#> 10    10  0      0      0      1     1      1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```r
dt |>
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, "year") |>
  arrange(ID, year) |>
  group_by(ID) |>
  mutate(x = {
    r <- accumulate(value,
                    ~max(0,.y + .x - 1),
                    .init = 0)
    pmin(1, value + head(r, -1))
  }) |>
  select(x, year, ID) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = "year", values_from = "x")

##> + # A tibble: 10 × 7
##> # Groups:   ID [10]
##>       ID `2015` `2016` `2017` `2018` `2019` `2020`
##>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
##>  1     1  0      0      0.685  1     0.0959 0.438 
##>  2     2  0.822  1      0.370  0.548 0      0     
##>  3     3  0      0      0      1     0.918  0     
##>  4     4  0.137  0.274  0.685  0     1      0.0959
##>  5     5  0      0      0      0     0      0.274 
##>  6     6  1      0.644  0.548  0     0.959  0.685 
##>  7     7  0.274  0      0      0     0.548  0     
##>  8     8  0.822  1      1      1     0.288  0     
##>  9     9  1      1      1      1     1      0     
##> 10    10  0      0      0      1     1      1
```